# Получить html таблицу в PHP массив

Tags: php, html, массивы

Добрый день,

Мне необходимо загрузить html таблицу `<table> </table>` в 2-у мерный массив. И если с базовым `<tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr>` все достаточно просто, то когда появляются у тега `<td >` атрибуты colspan=5 или rowspan=2 все становится совсем не тривиально. Есть ли библиотека или что-то подобное которая корректно обработает такую таблицу и загрузит даные в двумерный массив. В моем понимании корректно подразумеваю что если есть объедененная ячейка состоящая из 4-х ячеек (2х2 например) то в двумерном массиве будут находится 4-е элемента массива array(2х2), при этом в каждом будет одинаковое значение равное содержимому тега `<td colspan=2 rowspan=2> 777 </td>` и array[0][0]=array[0][1]=array[1][0]=array[1][1]=777. 
И если готового решения нет то буду рад если мне подскажут алгоритм как перебрать и обработать rowspan и colspan.

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код. Есть подозрение, что регулярные выражения не используются, или используются неправильно.

Comment: Обычные парсеры, dom парсеры и т.д. не подходят они не понимают сути значения rowspan и colspan для таблиц, кода нет пока не знаю с чего даже начать.